# UITabBar Appearance not working

Tags: ios, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I am trying to change the tint color of the UITabBarItem when it is selected with this line of code:

```
[[UITabBar appearance]setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:89 green:216 blue:239 alpha:1]];
```

However when I select the TabBar the tint color becomes white.

Anyone know why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In uicolor:RGB, you need to devide the value of 255.

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:89/255.0f green:216/255.0f blue:239/255.0f alpha:1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:89/255.0f green:216/255.0f blue:239/255.0f alpha:1]];

[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];//set rgb value if you want
```

Answer (score 1):

set the  selectedImageTintColor property to your color.

Answer (score 1):

Try this In your app delegate's didFinishLaunching method:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:89/255.0f green:216/255.0f blue:239/255.0f alpha:1]];
```

In iOS 7 use:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:89/255.0f green:216/255.0f blue:239/255.0f alpha:1]];
```